# How do you apply a maximum filter that ignores ties?

Tags: python, image-processing

I would like to transform an image in order to identify local maxima.

The desired output is an array that has the same shape as the input image, but only has binary values. "1" indicates a local maximum in a local 3x3 area, and 0 indicates that the pixel is not a local maximum.

The approach I have taken is to use scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter. This technique works, however in the case that there are two pixels that are maximum in the 3x3 area, both are given the value 1.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters

#here i have the top left corner of the famous image "Lena"
image = np.array(
      [[142, 142, 141, 140, 142, 136, 143, 140, 144],
       [142, 142, 141, 140, 142, 136, 143, 140, 144],
       [142, 141, 141, 140, 142, 136, 143, 140, 144],
       [142, 142, 141, 140, 142, 136, 143, 140, 144],
       [142, 141, 141, 140, 142, 136, 143, 140, 144],
       [144, 144, 137, 135, 140, 140, 138, 140, 140],
       [140, 140, 143, 138, 139, 143, 139, 137, 140],
       [138, 138, 135, 136, 138, 139, 136, 138, 138],
       [135, 136, 138, 137, 139, 139, 138, 137, 143]])

neighborhood = np.ones((3, 3), dtype = bool)

filtered = (filters.maximum_filter(image, footprint=neighborhood) == image)* 1

"""
Here is what the result looks like:
"""
filtered = np.array(
      [[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

If you look at the 'filtered' variable in the code snippet, observe that this filter picked up 5 local maxima in the top 3x3 corner. However if you look at the original image, there are a lot of 'ties' - that is, that the value 142 was not higher than the other pixels, but equal to the second highest.

I am also aware that the way that you handle border pixels is important, but my question still remains.

What should I do so that ties are awarded '0' and not '1'? For example pixel [1, 1] I would like to be 0.

Comment: may I ask what the purpose of that filter would be? why would you discard so many extrema, just because they are not isolated?

Comment: I am in the process of implementing the SIFT algorithm, in which an initial step is to identify extrema using local minima and local maxima. Keeping the maxima which are ties, results in a large number of initial keypoints, which slows down the algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform

Comment: This is not a convolution, please don’t call it a convolution. A convolution is a linear filter, the max is not linear. The max filter is a dilation.

Comment: To find these groups of pixels as a single maximum, you need an totally different algorithm. I have an implementation: https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__segmentation.html#ga0943ed74b85b3c8e2304fdf0da6be8cf

Answer (score 0):

Maximum filters are non-linear filters. You cannot use convolution to implement non-linear filters.

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

The maximum of (144,144,144) is 144. That's because of the mathematical definition of "maximum". If you don't like that you should not use a maximum filter.

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima

I suggest you implement your own filter that deals with that requirement.

Comment: What if one want to find the maxima (minima) map where a data point/pixel is considered as a local maximum (minimum), if its value is strictly higher (lower) than all of its neighbors?
Using OP matrix one would get:
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 ... 3 rows of 9 zeroes ...
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
instead of:
[[1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1]]
?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by applying a convolution with a 3x3 kernel to the maxima that I identified. Using this kernel creates an array where all the maxima that are 'tied' have a value greater than zero. Thereafter I just removed them.

```
import scipy.ndimage as nd
kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
new_maxima = nd.convolve(filtered, kernel)
new_maxima = np.where(new_maxima > 1, 0, new_maxima)
new_maxima = new_maxima * filtered
result = np.array(
       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

You can see that all the 'tied' maxima have been removed.